# disk failure is imminent

Tags: hard-drive

ok, i have one question, i got an error that my disk failure is imminent, i tryed everything possible to recover it but not success. then i completelly removed my ubuntu 12.04 by installing windows xp instead, but for some reasons, it now work fully with windows xp, but again suffers problems with ubuntu, displaying same message. is there any fix possible, please answer me quickly, i can not use windows i dont know lot to use it it s so hard. please help to back my best linux ever!!!!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/190671/smart-says-disk-failure-is-imminent-due-to-bad-blocks-what-do-i-need-to-do ?

Comment: your hard disk is going to fail soon. The self test are reporting that. Probably in XP, it doesn't recognize the result. Try windows 7, you will get the error. So backup your disk as early as possible

Comment: i allredy backuped. in wndows everithing works nice, just terminal or that cmd does not recognize any comand just cd. is that sure that it will fail, beacause it is really new one and 2tb disk??

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu is more sensitive to potential disk failure, and will tell you long before Windows does. **Heed the messages Ubuntu is giving you. Your drive *is* failing.** I don't care what Windows (especially XP) says. By the time Windows figures it out, you probably won't even be able to boot to the drive.

Yes, brand-new drives can fail. I've had this exact same thing happen with my Western Digital 1TB drive (it was a factory defect with that line of drives). Since it's brand new, you can get it replaced under the manufacturer's warranty. Do that ASAP.